# Object.values filter on 'keypress'

Tags: javascript, rxjs, javascript-objects, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

As I'm using this technique to get dummy data from **SWAPI**.

```
const httpStarwars$ = createHttpObservables('https://swapi.dev/api/films/');    
fromEvent<any>(this.sTxt.nativeElement,'keypress').pipe(
   map(event => event.target.value),
   debounceTime(400),
   distinctUntilChanged(),
   switchMap(val => httpStarwars$.pipe(
      map(res => Object.values(res["results"]))
   ))
).subscribe(courses => console.log(courses));
```

Here is the expected result after key press.

```
0: {title: "A New Hope", episode_id: 4, opening_crawl: "It is a period of civil war.
↵Rebel spaceships, st…er
↵people and restore
↵freedom to the galaxy....", director: "George Lucas", producer: "Gary Kurtz, Rick McCallum", …}
1: {title: "The Empire Strikes Back", episode_id: 5, opening_crawl: "It is a dark time for the
↵Rebellion. Although the… remote probes into
↵the far reaches of space....", director: "Irvin Kershner", producer: "Gary Kurtz, Rick McCallum", …}
2: {title: "Return of the Jedi", episode_id: 6, opening_crawl: "Luke Skywalker has returned to
↵his home planet of…
↵struggling to restore freedom
↵to the galaxy...", director: "Richard Marquand", producer: "Howard G. Kazanjian, George Lucas, Rick McCallum", …}
3: {title: "The Phantom Menace", episode_id: 1, opening_crawl: "Turmoil has engulfed the
↵Galactic Republic. The t…ustice in the
↵galaxy, to settle the conflict....", director: "George Lucas", producer: "Rick McCallum", …}
4: {title: "Attack of the Clones", episode_id: 2, opening_crawl: "There is unrest in the Galactic
↵Senate. Several t…THE REPUBLIC
↵to assist the overwhelmed
↵Jedi....", director: "George Lucas", producer: "Rick McCallum", …}
5: {title: "Revenge of the Sith", episode_id: 3, opening_crawl: "War! The Republic is crumbling
↵under attacks by t…ate mission to rescue the
↵captive Chancel
```

Now I want to filter the result of the above data below using filters.

```
map(res => Object.values(res["results"]))
```

What I will filter is `title`. So far what I used is this technique below.

```
map(res => Object.values(res["results"]).filter(j => j["title"] == res))
```

It gave me empty array like this `[]`.

**UPDATE 1:**

[image: array of object]

**Update 2:**
[image: error]

Comment: This `j["title"] == res` makes no sense at all. How you want to filter? By what condition?

Comment: @Bitman i want to filter "title" how do i filter the object values.

Comment: @Bitman from this JSON object .. {title: "A New Hope", episode_id: 4, opening_crawl: "It is a period of civil war.
↵Rebel spaceships, st…er
↵people and restore
↵freedom to the galaxy....", director: "George Lucas", producer: "Gary Kurtz, Rick McCallum", …}

Comment: `j["title"] == res` in here never true (most likely) because `res` is an Array, while title is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1**

I edit my answer to use Typescript.

---

I think that what you want to do is just filter your response by title, so you can just do that:

```js
interface Movie {
  title: string;
  episode_id: number;
}

const res = {};

res["results"] = { 
  0: {title: "A New Hope", episode_id: 4}, 
  1: {title: "The Empire Strikes Back", episode_id: 5 },
  2: {title: "Return of the Jedi", episode_id: 6}, 
  3: {title: "The Phantom Menace", episode_id: 1},
  4: {title: "Attack of the Clones", episode_id: 2} 
}

const result = Object.values(res["results"]).filter((movie: Movie) => movie.title === "A New Hope")

console.log(result)
```

Just remember to verify before if res["results"] contains the object with the movies.

Comment: It gives error like this on title. Property 'title' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: What is the return of Object.values(res["results"]) ? this should contain an array of objects...

Comment: I've updated my question it returns as the same you've done in the answer.

Comment: Even if I copy and paste your code it still gives me the .. Property 'title' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: If you are using typescript you must declare the type of movie, this is the problem.

Comment: An example would be helpful in this case for typescript.

Comment: interface Movie {
  title: string;
  episode_id: number;
}

And use like this:

const result = Object.values(res["results"]).filter((movie: Movie) => movie.title === "A New Hope")

Comment: @NamanKumar I edited my answer to use Typescript.

Comment: found the problem. I used the fixed value like this .. "A New Hope" it filtered. Now as i use the switchMap(val => httpStarwars$.pipe(
        map(res => {
          console.log(val);
          console.log(Object.values(res["results"]));
          const result = Object.values(res["results"]).filter((movie:Movie) => movie.title === val)
          return result;
        })
      )) it gives the first blank then value as in the console.log

Comment: "keyup" did the wonders instead of "keypress" which gave first blank then value.